# Lock whole directory until program ending

Tags: java, file, locking

I want to lock a whole directory using Java until the program ends, but I still want to write to the files from my program (so I want to deny write access to other programs). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What you ask has to do with the OS and the file system in use, so one way would be to change the owner to be your own user and deny permissions for group and others. Why do you want to do this? Maybe you should approach your challenge in a different manner.

Comment: @MortenKristensen I am storing temporary files but I don't actually keep any input/output stream open. Thats why I want to lock it.

Comment: The lock depends on the OS, keep that in mind. I would still set permissions accordingly to prevent change from others, or keep the file open (note that here the OS still plays its role on whether others can do the same anyway).

Answer (score -1):

use file.setWritable(false, false); which will prevent the writing to the folder

Comment: Is there a way to do so using NIO? And do I have to unlock the directory after the program ended or will it do that automatically?

Comment: It didn't work. I could delete that directory using the windows explorer.

Comment: try file.setExecutable(false);
       file.setReadable(false);
       file.setWritable(false);

Comment: Still not. Gonna try it on a single file instead of the whole dir, maybe that works. **EDIT:** Nope, it did not work.